# OWLAPI : How to get list of all Annotation Properties and Datatypes shows in protege

Tags: ontology, protege, owl-api

How to get list of all default annotations and datatypes using OWLAPI ?
Protege shows all list even though its not used in ontology.

`owlOntology.getAnnotationPropertiesInSignature()` and `owlOntology.getDatatypesInSignature()` both gives data which are either *Declared* OR *Used* in Ontology.

Following code is used as a work-around :

To get **Annotation** List :-

```
OWLDataFactory dataFactory = owlOntology.getOWLOntologyManager().getOWLDataFactory();
System.out.println(dataFactory.getOWLBackwardCompatibleWith());
System.out.println(dataFactory.getOWLDeprecated());
System.out.println(dataFactory.getOWLIncompatibleWith());
System.out.println(dataFactory.getOWLVersionInfo());
System.out.println(dataFactory.getRDFSComment());
System.out.println(dataFactory.getRDFSIsDefinedBy());
System.out.println(dataFactory.getRDFSLabel());
```

To get **Datatype** List :-

```
for (OWL2Datatype dt : OWL2Datatype.values()) {
            System.out.println(dt);
        }
```

is there any easy way ?

Answer (score 0):

The methods you mentioned have overloaded versions that accept an Imports value. Imports.INCLUDED will return the values including those from the imports closure.

Comment: Still overloaded method gives list which are either Used or Defined in imported ontology. To get list of all default annotation and datatypes I have done some work-around. Code is updated in question. Is there any simple way to do this ? I want to show all default names available just like Protege does.